# Unity3d Firebase and Google Play Game Services

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase, integration, google-play-games

Did anyone try to integrate Google Play Game Services and Firebase in Unity 3D?

**I'm interested in**
To have in my game the Google Play Game Services and the Firebase (Google Analytics at the beginning).

**What I did**
I downloaded current versions.

*Firebase: v 1.0.1*
plugin download link: firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup 
to Unity I only imported FirebaseAnalytics.unitypackage - because the main goal is to integrate Google Analytics (at the beginning of course)

*Google Play Game Services v 0.9.35*
plugin download link: github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

As you can notice after downloading those plugins the Firebase have Play Services Resolver at version 1.2.6.0 and Google Play Game Services have Play Services Resolver at version 1.2.2.0.

My current version of Unity: 5.2.4

**The Unity log informations**

```
Resolver version is now: 10101
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:RegisterResolver(IResolver)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:.cctor()
UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies:ProcessInitializeOnLoadAttributes()


Found dependencies:
com.google.android.gms:play-services-games required by (this app)
com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement required by (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.8+, com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:9+)
com.google.firebase:firebase-common required by (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.8+)
com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl required by (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.8+)
com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks required by (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.8+, com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9+)
com.google.android.gms:play-services-base required by (com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:9+)
com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive required by (com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:9+)
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base required by (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9+)
com.android.support:support-annotations required by (com.android.support:support-v4:23.1+)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:Log(String, Boolean)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:ResolveDependencies(Boolean)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:DoResolutionNoAndroidPackageChecks(PlayServicesSupport, String, OverwriteConfirmation)
GooglePlayServices.<DoResolution>c__AnonStorey1:<>m__0()
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:DoResolution(PlayServicesSupport, String, OverwriteConfirmation, Action)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Resolve(Action)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:AutoResolve()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()




WARNING: No compatible versions of com.google.android.gms:play-services-games required by (this app), will try using the latest version 10.0.1
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:Log(String, Boolean)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:ResolveDependencies(Boolean)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:DoResolutionNoAndroidPackageChecks(PlayServicesSupport, String, OverwriteConfirmation)
GooglePlayServices.<DoResolution>c__AnonStorey1:<>m__0()
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:DoResolution(PlayServicesSupport, String, OverwriteConfirmation, Action)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Resolve(Action)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:AutoResolve()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()




Found dependencies:
com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby required by (this app)
com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement required by (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.8+, com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:9+)
com.google.firebase:firebase-common required by (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.8+)
com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl required by (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.8+)
com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks required by (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.8+, com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9+)
com.google.android.gms:play-services-base required by (com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:9+)
com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive required by (com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:9+)
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base required by (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9+)
com.android.support:support-annotations required by (com.android.support:support-v4:23.1+)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:Log(String, Boolean)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:ResolveDependencies(Boolean)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:DoResolutionNoAndroidPackageChecks(PlayServicesSupport, String, OverwriteConfirmation)
GooglePlayServices.<DoResolution>c__AnonStorey1:<>m__0()
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:DoResolution(PlayServicesSupport, String, OverwriteConfirmation, Action)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Resolve(Action)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:AutoResolve()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()


WARNING: No compatible versions of com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby required by (this app), will try using the latest version 10.0.1
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:Log(String, Boolean)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:ResolveDependencies(Boolean)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:DoResolutionNoAndroidPackageChecks(PlayServicesSupport, String, OverwriteConfirmation)
GooglePlayServices.<DoResolution>c__AnonStorey1:<>m__0()
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:DoResolution(PlayServicesSupport, String, OverwriteConfirmation, Action)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Resolve(Action)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:AutoResolve()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

and so on... but when I press build for android it creates the APK file.
The problems occur when I try to launch the application.
Popup shows with the information "Unfortunately your application has stopped"

**Here is the logcat output**

```
E/AndroidRuntime(10074): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(10074): Process: com.Garmory.Test, PID: 10074
E/AndroidRuntime(10074): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa.zzb
E/AndroidRuntime(10074): at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.zza(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(10074): at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(10074): at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5052)
E/AndroidRuntime(10074): at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4647)
E/AndroidRuntime(10074): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4587)
E/AndroidRuntime(10074): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:159)
E/AndroidRuntime(10074): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1328)
E/AndroidRuntime(10074): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(10074): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
E/AndroidRuntime(10074): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
E/AndroidRuntime(10074): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10074): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(10074): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
E/AndroidRuntime(10074): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
E/AndroidRuntime(10074): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Could anybody help me with this issue?
I also tried to install new Play Services Resolver 1.2.6.0 (from github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver)

Thank you in advance.